# Why does $\int f(x) dx = \int_0^x f(t) dt$?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I feel like I am missing something fundamental as to why 
$$\int f(x) dx = \int_0^x f(t) dt$$

Sorry if this is a basic question. I just really want to know why they are equal and why we even have indefinite integrals if they are the same.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If $F$ is the antiderivative of $f$ then $$\int f(x) dx = F(x) + C$$ for some constant $C$, and $$\int_{0}^{x} f(t) dt = F(t) \bigg \lvert_{0}^{x} = F(x) - F(0)$$ where $F(0)$ is a constant.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that this is the [Fundamental Theorem of Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus).

Comment: If $F(x)= \int f(x)\,dx$ means $F'(x) = f(x),$ then $\int_0^x f(t)\,dt =\int f(x)\,dx $ by the FTC.

Comment: Thank you all. I see it now. I appreciate your time.

Comment: I guess as a follow up question though, why does the second integral need to go from 0 to x for this to be true? Like why doesn’t integral from 1 to x lead to equivalence?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\int f(x) dx$ isn't *one* function, but a *collection* of functions. $\int_0^x f(t)dt$ is one of those functions, as is $\int_3^x f(t) dt$. Some times, there are even functions which are not representable as $\int_a^x f(t) dt$.

Example: Take $f(x)=x$. Then $\int f(x) dx$ is the collection of functions of the form $\frac12x^2+C$ for all possible real numbers $C$. On the other hand, $\int_0^xf(t)dt=\frac12x^2$ is one such function, as is $\int_3^xf(t)dt=\frac12x^2-4.5$.

The function $\frac12x^2+1$ is also one of the functions included in $\int f(x)dx$, although it's impossible to construct it as $\int_a^xf(t)dt$ for any real number $a$.

WolframAlpha isn't always good at picking up such subtleties, and should therefore be trusted only to a certain degree with these things.